# Writing unusual cell array to .csv files from Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

So I was exploring the forum for this topic and could not find a relavent post that answered my question so here goes.  I want to save a cell array as a .csv file from Matlab.  The structure of my cell array is the following (and this is the part that is giving me trouble)

```
>> mycell

mycell = 

  Columns 1 through 8

    [76x1 double]    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    [76x75 double]    [76x1 double]    [76x1 double]    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}

  Columns 9 through 17

    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}    {76x1 cell}

  Column 18

    {76x1 cell}
```

So what I have been trying on my own to no avail is the following:

```
>> 
[nrows,ncols]= size(mycell);

filename = output_file;
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');

for row=1:nrows
    fprintf(fid, '%d,%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n', mycell{row,:});
end

fclose(fid);
??? Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The irregular structure of your cell array is going to make it difficult to write to a CSV file.  The first six indices are matrices whereas the remaining indices are all cell arrays. I suspect that converting them all to matrices will fix your problem.